# How to prove that there does not exist any plane isotopy from the logarithmic spiral onto the real line?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, planar-graphs

**Questions.**

EDIT: readers please note that while this question arose in research, the OP was so hung-up on a question concerning infinite planar graphs that a *strong a-forteriori-reason*, kindly pointed out by the answerer below, for why (A) is true was overlooked. The question as it stands is *trivial*. It will perhaps be *edited to include the (still open) graph theoretical question*, in due course. END OF EDIT

(0) How would you prove, in  *usual topology*, the following assertion:

(A) There does not exist any plane isotopy carrying the subset $S=\{ (\exp(t)\ \cos(t),\exp(t)\ \sin(t)|\quad t\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ 
onto the subset 
$R=\{ (t,0)|\quad t\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$.

(1) Independent of (0), in a bibliographic/reference-requestish vein:

(B) In what *literature references* does (something equivalent to) (A) *recognizably* appear? (I'm interested in as many relevant references as possible, in any of the media: book, lecture notes, research paper, website.)

**Remarks.**

- In $A$, all technical terms are standard terms of basic topology nowadays. The term *plane isotopy* would in some contexts often called by the more general term *ambient isotopy*. For what it's worth, a definition of the central notion here is the following.

Let

$\eta_S\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $\eta_S(t) =  (\exp(t)\cdot\cos(t),\exp(t)\cdot\sin(t))$,

and

$\eta_R\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $\eta_R(t) = (t,0)$.

Then a *plane isotopy* is any continuous set-map

$\theta\colon \mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$

satisfying the three axioms

(A.0) for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $v=\theta(v,0)$,

(A.1) for all $t\in[0,1]$, $v\mapsto\theta(v,t)$ defines a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$,

(A.2) $(v\mapsto \theta(v,1))\circ\eta_S = \eta_R$, equal as set-maps.

- I am less, but also, interested in *the* correct answer here, more in different writing- and proof-styles, some more efficient than others, localized at this very question.
- Of course, $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ 'looks' something like the blue line in the following illustration:
  [image]

(Made with Sage.)

- Motivation for this question is that (A) came up in research about (three-connected) *infinite planar graphs*, and I need to know more about and around it.

Comment: Why the emphasis on "classical logic"?  As opposed to what?  (I mean, most of mathematics uses classical logic by default: I find the qualification as bizarre as if my box of breakfast cereals advertised "does not contain plutonium!")

Comment: Dear Gro-Tsen, thanks for the question. To me, there is nothing bizarre about this and the *polemical* culinary and chemical words were brought in by *you*. Re "As opposed to what": as opposed to some well-known contemporary foundational research on how to prove certain basic statements of algebraic topology in non-classical logic, and which to describe this comment is too small. This is not about  one logic being right and the other wrong, these are *straight technical  matters*, "proof in classical logic" is just about as precisely defined as "proof in constructive logic" (modulo details).

Comment: @PeterHeinig Of course there is a contemporary foundational research, but by default, if you ask a question, it is in classical logic. You don't have to say it each time, hence the analogy in Gro-Tsen's comment.

Comment: The spiral is not a closed subset of the plane, while the line is, so they can't be identified by a homeomorphism of the plane, let alone an isotopy. Can you help me see what I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Stylistic changes in the question were made. Re Gro-Tsen's comment: Gro-Tsen is right that the emphasis on classical logic was misplaced, I did not notice this when writing the question. It just seems to me that the language of the comment was too inflammatory and the analogy a bit far-fetched.

Comment: If you are not going to explain how this is related to planar graphs, you should not use the tag [tag:planar-graphs].

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: re "you should not use the tag planar-graphs": thanks for the advice, this is an interesting view that a personal conviction that something is relevant is not sufficient, but that an explanation is necessary to justify a tag; this seems a reasonable rule-of-thumb. The full explanation of why I chose the tag is a long story: a small part of it is this: there is Whitney's theorem on the uniqueness-up-to-planar-isotopy of embeddings of *finite* 3-connected planar graphs into the plane. This was generalized to *infinite* graphs by several authors; a toy illustration of the [...]

Comment: My reason to say this is that tags are used by people to look for something. If somebody will search information on planar graphs and will be directed to your question, (s)he will not find anything related to her/his search (if you will not add the relevant information to the question).

Comment: [...] the additional difficulties that arise is the (of course, not 3-, not even 2-connected) planar graph $\dotsm\bullet\text{---}\bullet\text{---}\bullet\text{---}\bullet\text{---}\bullet\text{---}\dotsm$, which does not uniquely embed into the plane up to plane isotopy e.g. for the evident reason that the embedding corresponding to $S$ in the OP is not equivalent w.r.t. plane isotopy to the embedding corresponding to $R$. There is much more to be said on this. If interested, you could start in and around Carsten Thomassen's papers from the early 1980s on the topic. Thanks again for asking.

Comment: @PeterHeinig I'm sorry you found my comment offensive, it was not meant to be.  (The analogy was mostly meant to be funny — I think there was an xkcd comic along those lines, even though I can't find it any more.  But it was also meant to convey my sincere confusion and my impression that I was missing something.)

Comment: Peter, best MO practice is not to edit the question to ask another question, but to open a new question.

Comment: Todd, thanks for pointing out. I only intend to edit in research background, not ask the open question as an MO question. I am only trying to constructively respond to "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question." in the "on-hold" message. I recognize that "reworded" does not primarily mean to add a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A stronger result is true: there is no homeomorphism of the plane which takes the spiral to the line.
If the spiral is defined exactly as in your question (does not contain the origin) this is evident:
your spiral in not a closed subset of the plane, while the line is.

But even if you add the origin to
your definition of the spiral, the result still holds. Simply because the spiral with the origin added is not homeomorphic to the line.

Comment: Thank you. I had intentionally not added the origin since I thought "Now *that* would really trivialize the question." since, like you said, then $R$ and $S$ would not even be homeomorphic (which in the OP they are). FYI: adding the origin correspond to adding an [end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(graph_theory)) to the double ray (if one associates a two-way infinite double ray graph with the spiral).